# want 3 divs to appear when hovering over another

Tags: css, html, hover

So here is my code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>An MSU Soiree</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<html>
<body>

<div id="one"> <h2 id="h1"> An MSU Soiree</h2> </div>

<div id="two"> <h2 id="2h"> Campus</h2>
<div id="a"> </div>
<div id="b"> </div>
<div id="c"> </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and some of my css.... it repeats so it doesn't matter.

```
#2h
{
font-family:Courier;
text color:white;   
text-align: center;
}

#two
{
width:100%;
height:80px;
background-color:#FF0056;
}

#a
{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color: white;
}

#b
{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color: white;
}


#c
{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color: white;

}



#two:hover 
{
height:225px;
background-color:#FF0056;
}

#two: hover div #a, #b, #c
{
display:inline-block;
}
```

so as you can see, without being hovered, the box width is 100%, height of 80. When hovered, it is 225 height, 100% width.
but when hovered, i would like 3 divs to appear in the hovered div, split horizontally evenly, and centered in terms of height.

what tweaks are required to create this fantasy haha?

also, when i try to center a header such a #2h, the text still stays in the left. my other small dilemma.

Comment: First thing - put your HTML tag above `<head>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This effect can be accomplished in two ways: through pure CSS, or with JavaScript.

**Pure CSS Method**

1. Set each of the interior divs (#a, #b, and #c) to `display: none;`. This will make the divs hidden by default (when the user is not hovering over the parent div (#two).
2. Create a decedent selector for the hover effect. It would look something like this: `#two:hover #a, #two:hover #b, #two:hover #c {}`. This rule is applied to the #a, #b, and #c divs only when the user hovers over #two.
3. Inside the decedent selector, set the interior divs to `display: inline-block;`.

Check out this simple example (it could certainly use some polishing but you can see the three interior divs appearing on hover):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
    #a {
        display: none;
        background-color: red;
        width: 30%; 
    }
    #b {
        display: none;
        background-color: blue; 
        width: 30%;
    }
    #c {
        display: none;
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 30%; 
    }
    #two {
        background-color: #666;
        border: 3px solid black;
        width: 100%;    
    }
    #two:hover #a, #two:hover #b, #two:hover #c {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="two"> <h2 id="2h"> Campus</h2>
        <div id="a"> 
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
        </div>
        <div id="b"> 
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
        </div>
        <div id="c"> 
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, this method is nice because it uses pure CSS, but the drawback is that there is no animation.

**jQuery Method**

Therefore, the appearance of the three interior divs is a bit abrupt. You could use JavaScript (or even better jQuery) to animate the appearance of the interior divs. A very simple example of a jQuery script to animate the hover effect might look something like this:

```
$("#two").hover(function() {
    $("#a").fadeIn(250);
    $("#b").fadeIn(250);
    $("#c").fadeIn(250);    
}, function() {
    $("#a").fadeOut(250);
    $("#b").fadeOut(250);
    $("#c").fadeOut(250);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a JSFiddle that should do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/MP8vE/

This is the most relevant CSS:

```
#a {
    width:33%;
    height:50px;
    background-color: white;
    display:none;
    float:left;
}
#b {
    width:33%;
    height:50px;
    background-color: blue;
    display:none;
    float:left;
}
#c {
    width:33%;
    height:50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display:none;
    float:left;
}
.two:hover div {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block !important;
}
```